# On executing code in MacOS terminal, shows unexpected token

Tags: macos, unexpected-token

```
echo "Enter A in Quadratic equation Ax^2+Bx+C=0"
read a
echo "Enter B"
read b
echo "Enter C"
read c
count=0
Dis=$(((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))
if [ $Dis -gt 0 ]
then
count=1
elif [ $Dis -lt 0 ]
then
count=2
else
count=3
fi
case "$count" in
"1")
root1=$(((-b) - (sqrt($Dis))) / (2 * a))
root2=$(((-b) + (sqrt($Dis))) / (2 * a))
echo "The roots are:"
echo $root1
echo $root2
;;
"2")
echo "Roots are imaginary"
;;
"3")
root=`expr (-b) / (2 * a)`
echo "The singular root is:"
echo $root
;;
esac
```

I’m using MacOS terminal. This program should be able to find the quadratic roots of the equation using a case statement.I’m using zsh shell and I don’t have sqrt() function installed in my Mac.

The error occurs in the case statement, in line 20 and 21 . It says syntax error near unexpected token `-‘ and for` +’. Those two formulas are for calculating roots of the equation for case count equals to one. It gives same error for count equals 3 which doesn’t even have sqrt() function.

First how do I install sqrt() function?

Second what’s the error with the syntax?

I’m thankful for any help

Comment: Also this program is created in a directory in a file using the cat command , and executed with chmod +x file name and ./filename

Comment: The parentheses aren't properly balanced. You need one fewer close parenthesis after `sqrt($Dis)` and one more at the end if the expression.